# .dir-locals.el setting coding system dependeing on subdirectory

Tags: emacs, elisp

This is my directory layout.

```
 projects/   
   portal/   
   project1/   
   project2/
```

I want "portal" subdirectory to have buffer-file-coding-system set to utf-8-unix. While for the other subdirectories I want buffer-file-coding-system set to utf-8-dos. .dir-locals.el file looks like this and is placed in root of projects directory.

```
((nil
  (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-dos))
 ("portal"
  (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-unix)))
```

When I open any file from any folder buffer-file-coding-system is set to utf-8-dos, even if it is a file from "portal" subdirectory. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry under `"portal"` should contain not a list of variable bindings, but an alist of modes and variable binding lists - just like the top level of `.dir-locals.el`.  This seems to work:

```
((nil
  (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-dos))
 ("portal"
  . ((nil (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-unix)))))
```